# Can one spread rich snippet breadcrumbs markup all over a page?

Tags: html, links, rich-snippets, markup, breadcrumbs

From [here](http://schema.org/WebPage), we have an example of a rich snippet breadcrumb implementation:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
...
<div itemprop="breadcrumb">
  <a href="category/books.html">Books</a> >
  <a href="category/books-literature.html">Literature & Fiction</a> >
  <a href="category/books-classics">Classics</a>
</div>
```

The breadcrumbs are grouped under a `div`. Unfortunately, a page does not necessarily group its `a` links in one place.

Can one spread rich snippet markup like this?

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
...
<p>
  Bla bla bla some text <a itemprop="breadcrumb" href="category/books.html">Books</a> > bla bla bla. 
  Bla bla ble more text <a itemprop="breadcrumb" href="category/books-literature.html">Literature & Fiction</a> > bla bla bla.
  Some more text about more topics bla bla bla <a itemprop="breadcrumb" href="category/books-classics">Classics</a> bla bla bla. 
</p>
```

Or will the following work too (i.e., the `itemprop` is inherited by all `a` links like css)?

```
<p itemprop="breadcrumb">
  Bla bla bla some text <a href="category/books.html">Books</a> > bla bla bla. 
  Bla bla ble more text <a href="category/books-literature.html">Literature & Fiction</a> > bla bla bla.
  Some more text about more topics bla bla bla <a href="category/books-classics">Classics</a> bla bla bla. 
</p>
```

If breadcrumb links are spread all over a page, what is the right way to set the rich snippet markup for these?

Comment: Surely it wouldn't really be breadcrumb navigation if they were spread out that much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, markup can be spread all over the page. In fact, you can try it out with Google's own [Structured Data Markup Helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/), which will allow you to highlight items on a page and see suggested marked-up HTML.